# Tool bar is missing on stack overflow

Tags: discussion, bug

Tool bar is missing on stack overflow while i tried to post a question, so i can't format my code and links. I can see only add picture button. How can i fix this ? I tried with manual coding, but it's also not working.

[image][image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of it

Comment: I can't post an image, because it need at least 10 reputation.

Comment: Now i added the image, But i can't see it here ... Can you see it ?

Comment: I think there is some serious issues with the website.

Comment: can you post and image of the address bar?

Comment: I added screenshot 2 times, as you can see its not displaying picture, Its just showing the text "enter image description here." See on the top.

Comment: What if you visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask directly?

Comment: It's the same, i can't see tools, Only Picture add button is there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a mobile browser? That happens when using the mobile browser to post questions. Hope Stackoverflow will fix this. If you want to view with the toolbar, click on `Request Desktop Site` on your browser.

Comment: I am using in Desktop.

Comment: The layout in the image looks like a mobile webpage indeed... :S

Comment: But i am using a desktop. I don't know why its happening ....

Comment: You are using the mobile skin nevertheless; you get back to the desktop version by clicking the "full site" link e.g. at the very bottom of your first screen shot. (When you are on the desktop version it displays a "mobile" link; you probably clicked this by accident at some point.)

Comment: Yes, Now it's fine... But i think it's a bug.

Comment: I'm on a desktop and the toolbar is missing (wasn't missing before). I'm using desktop site as well (no "request desktop site" button available, only "mobile").